# Use custom Application for Espresso testing with Mockito

Tags: java, android, mockito, android-espresso, ui-testing

This question may be trivial but I am new to Android so bear with me.

I am trying to use Mockito and Espresso to test my application. I have followed instructions [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator) and [here](http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/12/mock-application-in-espresso.html#comment-form) to create a MockApplication (that extends Application), MockApplicationComponent, and MockApplicationModule.

In my test class I try to setup the application like this....

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<OnboardActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

@Before
public void setup() {

    Application app = mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getApplication();
    TestApplication testApp;

    if (!(app instanceof TestApplication)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to downcast "+app.getClass().toString());
    }
    testApp = (TestApplication) app;

    MockApplicationModule module  = new MockApplicationModule(testApp);
    .......
    .......
}
```

and here is the TestApplication

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {
private ApplicationModule applicationModule;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
}

@Override
ApplicationModule getApplicationModule() {
    return new MockApplicationModule(this);
}

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    try {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
    } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
        // Multidex support doesn't play well with Robolectric yet
    }
}

// We store an instance of application module because we want to be able to
// override in our test setup later
public void setApplicationModule(ApplicationModule mApplicationModule) {
    this.applicationModule = mApplicationModule;
    initComponent();
}

@Override
protected void initComponent() {
    component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(getApplicationModule())
            .build();
}}
```

Obviously, i'm improperly downcasting in the test class and am always receiving the runtime exception.

What is the best way to get the Activity to use the TestApplication and not the Application?

Thank You.

Comment: Have you created dedicated `AndroidManifest.xml` file for test bulds, where you have registered `TestApplication` as the application class of the project?

Comment: @azizbekian I have an AndroidManifest.xml for my dev build yes. However, I specify the parent class 'Application' here because when I change to 'TestApplication' I get an 'unresolved class' 'error.